# Есть ли возможность запуска *.exe файлов в Linux ?

Tags: unix, exe, linux

Собственно, есть ли возможность запуска *.exe файлов в Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Wine](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wine) для Windows
[DosBox](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosbox) для DOS

Comment: Или dosemu. Смотря какой екзешник.

Answer (score -1):

Под Linux eсть возможность запуска любых файлов, хоть *.txt:

```
chmod +x filename
./filename
```

Comment: wtf? вы из этого мира?

Comment: А что тут такого?

         cat <<wtf >a.txt
         #!/bin/sh
         echo Вот вам!
         wtf
         chmod +x a.txt
         ./a.txt

Comment: >Под Linux eсть возможность запуска любых файлов, хоть *.txt

Вот эта фраза хоть *.txt и есть бред. Вопрос стоит в запуске *.exe файлов. Не видел ни одного простите "умного" человека который хотел бы запустить файл для чтения на выполнение (исключения это php и другие языки программирования).

Так что ответ не по сути вообще ибо он немного бредоват.

Comment: @dzhioev, Вы предлагаете полюбоваться на строки типа:

    ./xaxa: line 1: djkjdj: command not found
    ./xaxa: line 2: dkdkkdkdk: command not found

???

Comment: Ну немного есть. Но "на бредовые вопросы мы даём ещё более бредовые ответы". Ответ @dzhioev -- самый правильный из представленных. Бред -- вопрос @Basm. Данный ответ ему вполне удовлетворяет. То, что @Basm хотел узнать что-то другое и более полезное для себя -- совсем другая история. По крайней мере, какие екзешники ему надо запускать, он героически умолчал. @avp "запущен" и "делает то, что мне надо" -- немного разные вещи.

Comment: @alexlz так зачем давать бредовые ответы на бредовые вопросы? Замечу, что тут столько читателей которые потом используют как бредовые, так и не бредовые ответы, а потом ломаются сервера на которых висят большие проекты (ну так к слову)

Comment: На самом деле вопрос не такой уж и бредовый. Вас же не удивляет, что системный вызов execl() позволяет запустить shell скрипт ? 

Что мешает сделать версию Linux, запускающую файл под Wine ?

Comment: @Shrek вероятно да. Но вопросы, состоящие из двух частей: "угадай, что я спросил" (1) и "ответь" (2), причём (2) намного проще (1) -- утомляют. @avp Вы про что? Если установлен wine, то виндовые экзешники под ним и запускаются... (Зависит это, конечно не от расширения, а от magic).

Comment: Что мешает вообше один дистрибутив Линя выпустить как windoвый. и потом блевать :)

есть wine радуемся. Просто я лично не виже смысла соединять win и linux. запускать на одном файлы от другого.

Comment: @alexlz, вот Вы это знали, **а я нет**. Насчет wine, а не magic, естественно. 

Ответили бы сразу и развернуто (не ссылкой на вики) на вопрос и обогатили бы знания других.

Т.е. sudo apt-get install wine1.3  и вперед ? После этого виндовый ./HelloWorld.exe нарисует буковки на gnome-terminal ?

Comment: @avp ну у меня установлен wine1.2. Ну и chmod +x ... А так -- да, только запускается медленно -- пока ещё wine стартанёт... @Shrek Зачем запускать? А зачем винда? если нужно запустить виндовую задачу, так Windows покупать? Пример: школы, там какая-то хрень (забыл название)(вспомнил -- Хронограф) на 1С. 1С -- виндовая. Или плати за лицензии MSWin, или работай под wine. Правда были какие-то заморчки с лицензиями на wine, и с разрешением школам (временно?) использовать её (wine) для этих целей. Точнее сказать не могу -- гугл/яндекс в помощь.